How to get timestamp was created NFT Position?
I have a 1 NFT position (Nonfungible Position Manager) and I want get timestamp was created this NFT to convert to age time.

Please share more details, like contract address, transaction hash, etc.

timestamp goes in the block header which processed your transaction, get the receipt of the transaction and check the block number, the block has timestamp field

I was use react with Web3React to get age nft position but i don't known function get timestamp from NFT contract.
NFT contract: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xaf7aEBA8F1A42C0cb44C950D2a66E9EaB22bf19c
And NFT Position: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0xaf7aeba8f1a42c0cb44c950d2a66e9eab22bf19c?a=0x11503e1ba556340aec6416b25d8c1b06ab04c800
